# MKMapKit Follow User

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

How can I have my `MKMapView` follow my user around until they scroll, and then have a button to follow the user around again?

Here is the flow I would like it to have.

**View Loads:**
Zoom in and center on the users current location, then follow the user around.

**User scrolls:**
Do nothing until a button is pressed

**Button pressed:**
Same code as 'View Loads'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your location manager is continuously providing you with new location information via the delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`. Change the map's region whenever you get an update. Before doing so, check a flag ("`shouldFollowCurrentLocation`" or similar) that is set by default. You will unset the flag when your map view delegate gets `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` (you will of course have to keep track of the occasions when you cause the region to change programmatically) and reset it in the button's action method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my `MKMapKit` is not sending a message that says `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: Updated; I thought `MKMapView`s were enclosed in scroll views.

Comment: Works well, thanks! (I'm not sure where my previous comment went, but again, this works.)

Comment: Another update! For those developing for iOS 5.0 this behavior (all of it) is implimented by calling `[map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];`. Feel free to read more about it here, but it works just like the Google Maps application (with one line of code). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userTrackingMode